# Problems with pagination in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

In any way I can not fasten pagination to this page:
[page of discounts](http://www.staff-demo.pp.ua/skidki/)
I use woocommerce with theme:
[savoy.nordicmade.com](http://savoy.nordicmade.com/)

I bring out discounts by a shortcode:

```
[sale_products per_page="8" pagination="true"]
```

Install the plugin "Shortcode Pagination for WooCommerce" ... On the category page (from the theme box) everything works, on the discounts page - no (connected already necessary scripts, but still does not work) ...

What else have I missed?